# How to create Unity3d gaussian plume resembling breathing puffs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, simulation, gaussian, gravity

I'm working on a project that needs a breath effect such that it emits puffs of droplets for visualization.  The puffs need to occur about 10-20 times per minute and look like water vapor expelled during cold weather.  I've created several particle generators in Unity that use a cone shaped emitter and tried to adjust it to get something similar to a gaussian plume, but all I get are "rings" and I can't get one generator to create short "puffs".  I finally have created 3 generators pithing the same "cone", one emits small particles, one medium sized, and the other large, but it does not resemble a collection of particles that change size after being breathed out, i.e. shrinking due to evaporation, slowing down to terminal velocities appropriate to their changing size, drifting upward due to the thermal gradient in the room, etc.  Can someone point me to the documentation that explains how to create a particle generator that would provide for spatially distributed, velocity distributed, size distributed particles where the "puff" could be characterized by vz_avg, vz_sigma, vx_avg = vy_avg, vx_sigma = vy_sigma, and be able to have each particle's speed and acceleration a function of it's size, temperature difference between it and background, evaporation due to humidity and temp, etc?

The Unity engine is good at allowing one to put an avatar into a scene, move and control it representing almost realistic looking behavior, BUT, my difficulty is combining video effects in a manner that is physically realistic, i.e. gravity, buoyancy, evaporation, slowing down, etc.

Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a series of parameters put together that allowed me to perform this task.  I had to use three different emitters, one for large droplets, one for mid range droplets, and one for aerosols.  Each used a different setting for gravity to emulate falling, hovering, and rising particles, restpectively.  By matching the rate of emission of the "puffs" to the human breathing, the number of particles to approximate the number of viral droplets of the different sizes that have been determined to be in a breath, I was able to create a realistic "looking" cloud of particles that are emitted, drift to the floor, hover, and also rise towards the ceiling.

I just thought I'd post and answer so that others might know that it can be done, but takes a lot of working backwards from the actual physics to the way that Unity displays things to get something realistic.